# How to set maximum file size for a samba share?

Tags: samba

Is there any way to limit the maximum file size of files that users are allowed to upload to a samba (linux) share? I could not find anything in the documentation, but it seems like the kind of thing that should exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, such a thing does not exist.

You can however set file-size limits with web servers (definitely NGINX, likely Apache, probably others) so using those to manage an upload/download site - or possibly WebDAV - could help you manage that restriction.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will do that.  Thanks. I would vote you up, but I do not have enough reputation.